# Select class with selenium python

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver

Hi I'm trying to automate a process with selenium, python and GLPI, but recently I spend a lot o f time trying to select a user of a menu bar,I already did tests with linkText,cssSelector,xpath but none works for me, Maybe I'll be doing it wrong, I appreciate your help.

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'javascript:void(0)') and contains(.,'select2-choice')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*='select2-container select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open']").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("javascript:void(0)").click()
```

https://ibb.co/RbrXDrv  that is the code source

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open" id="s2id_dropdown__users_id_requester722037505" style="width: 80%;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-4">-----</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen4" class="select2-offscreen"></label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-4" id="s2id_autogen4" disabled=""></div>
```

thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output. Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is not correct.

Try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='javascript:void(0)' and @class='select2-choice']").click()
```

BTW, it would be better to provide url or html, not picture.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer i try that code but still not working i put the source code